# Searchkick different reindex results when not reindex all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Im using searchkick.

```
Product.reindex
```

This will reindex all the records, and it will works if I search with:

```
Product.search "*", load: false
```

or

```
Product.search "something", load: false
```

But for development purpose only, I only want to for example, 10 records only. So I did this:

```
Product.take(10).each do |p| p.reindex end
```

But it won't work with the search method like I did before.

My questions is:

- How to reindex only a view records? not all the records.

Answer (score 2):

By default, searchkick will index automatically all new record (on create/update/delete). So if you want to index only 10 records, you may have to:

1. Disable automatic indexing, by using this in your model:

   searchkick callbacks: false
2. Remove all previous index:

   Product.clean_indices
3. Index the 10 records you want:

   Product.take(10).each{|p| p.reindex}

Hope this helped, i did not test it, just red a bit of documentation.

Comment: I miss the `searchkick callbacks: false` will try and post the result. Thanks bro ;)